# Excel to sql table :SSIS package design pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, ssis

Is there any particular performance pattern to be followed ,while developing a ssis package to extract data from excel files to table ..There are several excel files in the source system and need to be loaded on the table in sql server..it takes several hours to complete the whole load..

The package consist of excel source component and the oledb destination(with fast load)
Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

You can put all excel file into one folder .and use a for each loop container to load data into sql server.package should like  this.
1-drag a foreachloop container in control flow task.
2- drag a dataflow task inside the foreach loop container 
in the for eachloop container choose for each file enumerator and store the connection into a variable.
in the data flow task  drag excel source and sql server destination.